# Is it possible to check if the source code matches the App version?

Tags: android, security, binary-reproducibility

Germany (SAP / Telekom) built a Corona-App. It's available in the [Android Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.rki.coronawarnapp&hl=de) and the [code is on Github](https://github.com/corona-warn-app/cwa-app-android).

Is it possible to check if the code on Github matches the code in the Android Store?

Comment: See also [reproducible builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds).

Comment: @schroeder Can you move it or should I close and create a new one?

Comment: @ADM I'm not sure what you are suggesting. How would I make sure that the app version `1.3.0` is the same as the git tag version `1.3.0`?

Comment: SOP is to tag the repository with released version, so tag `1.3.0` is same as app version `1.3.0` on Android Store. FYI you can't overwrite debug build on top of the app installed from store because app keys are different.